# MySQL decimal memory usage (signed v unsigned)

Tags: mysql, decimal

I understand the memory storage requirements for the MySQL decimal number (eg. DECIMAL(5,2) requires 2 bytes for the 3 integers and 1 for the decimals. But I notice that decimal can also be signed or unsigned.

With numbers such as TINYINT, the range varies depending on whether it is signed (-128 to 127) or unsigned (0-255). My question then is does the memory usage for decimals change if they are signed or unsigned? Would -999.99 to 999.99 use the same memory as 000.00 to 999.99?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to change from version to version. Here's information for how it's implemented in 5.6.

[The MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) don't talk about the effect of signage and suggest diving into the source of `decimal2bin()` for details. There's a big comment in there about the storage format.

```
This binary format is as follows:
  1. First the number is converted to have a requested precision and scale.
  2. Every full DIG_PER_DEC1 digits of intg part are stored in 4 bytes
     as is
  3. The first intg % DIG_PER_DEC1 digits are stored in the reduced
     number of bytes (enough bytes to store this number of digits -
     see dig2bytes)
  4. same for frac - full decimal_digit_t's are stored as is,
     the last frac % DIG_PER_DEC1 digits - in the reduced number of bytes.
  5. If the number is negative - every byte is inversed.
  5. The very first bit of the resulting byte array is inverted (because
     memcmp compares unsigned bytes, see property 2 above)
```

The key is "*5. If the number is negative - every byte is inversed.*", so the answer is that signed or unsigned has no effect on `DECIMAL` storage size.

Comment: Thanks for that. So it seems the only reason to make a decimal unsigned is to prevent invalid entries.

Answer (score 8):

> Would -999.99 to 999.99 use the same memory as 000.00 to 999.99?

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer:

- The digits to the left of the decimal point and the digits to right are each considered to be whole numbers.
- Those on the left have a sign, but it does not take up any extra space.
- Each group (on left or right) of 9 digits fits in 4 bytes; less than 9 takes up ceil(N/2) bytes.

A simple rule of thumb:  "`DECIMAL(m,n)` takes `m/2` bytes."  It's not always exact, but it is very close.

I think the last major change in DECIMAL was in 5.0.5.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, decimal(13,2) is 9 bytes and decimal(10,2) is 5 bytes?

Comment: `(13,2)` is 5+1 bytes: 5 bytes for left of decimal point, plus 1 more for right of decimal.  `(10,2)` is 4+1 bytes.

Comment: Hi, this is great, does this still apply to latest versions of MariaDB ?

Comment: @theMyth - I see no hint that MariaDB changed the implementation after splitting from MySQL.  (The split happened after 5.0.5.).